# How to fix 'Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, database

I am trying to connect to the MySQL database with Python. I am running following code

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import pyodbc 

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                             database='data1',
                             user='username',
                             password='xxxx')
```

and get the error message

```
InterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Comment: install MySQL server? :)

Comment: There is either no local MySQL server running or a firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: @FlashThunder I am using MSSQLSERVER

Comment: @PankajGarg so no wonder it doesn't work... you are trying to use `mysql` connector on it.

Comment: @KlausD. in the services, it is showing MSSQLSERVER is running. And how to check if firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: @PankajGarg it doesn't matter, you are trying to connect to MSSQL with MYSQL connectior, it's not even on the same port. MSSQL is on 1433 by default.

Comment: @FlashThunder What to use then? If you can help with the hint

Comment: @PankajGarg check my answer, can't give a code in here.

Comment: @FlashThunder I now tried with port 1433 and same error "InterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:1433' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)"

Comment: @PankajGarg you should really tell us the O/S and the database in your question, not just in the comments.  You can edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using MySQL driver to connect to MS SQL, which won't work… What you need is something like this:

```
   import pymssql  
   conn = pymssql.connect(server='localhost', user='username', password='xxxx', database='data1')
```

Comment: But another error comes up "OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (localhost:1433)\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10060)\n')"

Comment: open the access to your 127.0.0.1:1433 in the SQL server Configuration Manager, eventually check if the server is not running on some random port (afaik it randomizes it recently), check the first answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348255/pymssql-operationalerror-db-lib-error-message-20009-severity-9

Comment: 18452, b'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (localhost:1433)\n')

Comment: this is a problem with your authentication method, not with python itself, it connects correctly... you need to configure your MSSQL properly, I am not using MSSQL at all, so sorry, but can't help you with that, maybe ask another question about it?

Comment: OperationalError: (18452, b'DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 11:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed (localhost:1433)\n')

Comment: I have to store large number of XML files. So MSSQL was the only option that come up. If you can suggest better database to store xml files

Comment: MySQL is fine as well, a bit easier to configure imo.