# Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (EFSPC14)\nDB-Lib error message 20009, severity

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql, sqlconnection

I am new to python, I am writing small program in which I need to access the database from local machine's ( EFSPC14) SQLEXPRESS server . For that I used  pymssql library and wrote the below piece of code in order to connect to SQLEXPRESS server installed on my local machine.

*import pymssql

mydbb = pymssql.connect(server ='EFSPC14\SQLEXPRESS', user='sa', password='sa123', database='PythonAutomation')*

But, when I execute this code , I got the error as shown below:

**"severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (EFSPC14)\nDB-Lib error message 20009"**

I can connect and work on this sqlexpress server directly but through above code , it was not connect.

Please advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pymssql.OperationalError: DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348255/pymssql-operationalerror-db-lib-error-message-20009-severity-9)

Comment: Thanks for link shared by you , I tried all answers from your shared link apart from using pyodbc liabrary. But it does not fix my issue , please advice

Comment: First you must make sure that the instance of sql server (in this case `SQLEXPRESS`) is available over network. You need to find out on what port it is running (default is 1433). And check through a terminal (like command prompt) if this is accessible or not. Here is the telnet command for this purpose `telnet 127.0.0.1 1433`.

Comment: Thanks for reply , but when I restart my machine and tried again , it start working , now my code no longer throws the error and I am able to retrived the data from database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all TCP/IP should be enabled for communication. For that please follow the given below steps,

**SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS**
*TCP/IP must be enabled*
[image]
and in **Properties -> IP Addresses -> IPAll**
*TCP Port must be set*[image]

Then set connection string as,

*conn = pymssql.connect(host='localhost',server='EFSPC14\SQLEXPRESS', port='1433',user='sa', password='sa123', database='PythonAutomation',as_dict=True, login_timeout=3)*