# Unable to connect to SQL server using PYMSSQL

Tags: python, pyodbc, pymssql

I encounter this problem when trying to connect to my SQL database:

```
OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (LAPTOP-B3TE2LKC)\nDB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (LAPTOP-B3TE2LKC)\n')
```

I am able to connect to my database with the very same credentials using PYODBC, so the access variables should be fine.

Does anyone know how to solve this error message? - I am using Python version 3.8.8 and PYMSSQL version 2.2.2.

This is my code, including the credentials I used to connect to this test database:

```
import pymssql
print(pymssql.__version__)

# Database credentials and variables
server = 'LAPTOP-B3TE2LKC\TESTEXPRESS'
user = 'FTP-user'
password = '1111'
database = 'TestA'

# Connect to SQL database
database_connection = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, database)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can try solutions from this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348255/pymssql-operationalerror-db-lib-error-message-20009-severity-9

Comment: In order for pymssql to resolve `LAPTOP-B3TE2LKC\TESTEXPRESS` the "SQL Server Browser" service must be running on that machine.

Comment: @GordThompson you should turn your comment into an answer, because the solution you proposed worked for me, having the same issue. And then the OP may choose your answer as accepted :)